# All icons are Internet Explorer

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, icons

My partner was doing something on our laptop, and now all our icons look the same (the Internet Explorer icon). When you open something up (eg Windows Media Player), it goes straight to Internet Explorer, everything I open is Windows Explorer.

How do I get them back to their original icons?

Comment: Sounds like you may have been the victim of a virus attack.  Check the system for viruses.

Comment: Get a new partner.

Comment: As Matt says, this sounds like it's probably a virus attack - have a look at the question [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

Comment: Sounds like a practical joke to me :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try Windows 7's built in [System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/What-is-System-Restore) to go back to a point before this happened?

Answer (score 0):

I think that a system restore would be worth a try, as well. Also, you might want to consider running Microsoft Security Essentials just to make sure that there isn't anything harming your computer: http://www.microsoft.com/security_essentials/

Answer (score 0):

Working from the command line might bypass this. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, then type `cmd`, then click **OK**. Obviously, you'll need to know how to do this. Also:

> it goes straight to Internet Explorer, everything I open is Windows Explorer.

Contradicting statements: Internet Explorer browses the web, and Windows Explorer browses files on your computer.